# Https protocol in iis does not load fonts and images from content folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am developing a small project using ASP.NET MVC 5 on my local machine.

Everything is good as I planned, but when I publish it on production server which is iis on Windows Server 2016 and using protocol https and http, there are symptoms:

- when I browse the project using http protocol everything is ok
- but when I browse to it using https, fonts and images do not load as expected  and I get an error 404.

Please can I get any help?

With my thanks in advance.

*Note*: the production server is virtual machine and it is managed using Plesk control panel

- I tried to manage permissions and authentication roles of root folder of my project but no result.
- I checked that static content is enabled.

Comment: You might enable FRT to dig further into those 404 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Comment: Have you tried to set anonymous user authentication credentials? Go to IIS, select your website and go to Authentication panel, If anonymous is enabled, click on edit in the Actions panel and then select Application pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all of who was attempting to help, i figured out that problem, it was about plesk has **Url.Rewrite** rule that enforce request in some way which cause that problem, just i deleted it then every thing become Ok